# add a transparent div on top of gmaps map

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to be able to add a transparent div on top of the gmap generated map.

I tried to set z-index very high but it did not help

Here my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gmap basic example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
        <script src="gmaps.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width:100%; height: 350px;">

            <div id="topmapiv" style="width:100%; height: 50px; z-index:1000000000000;">hjajjs hjhsjdjd</div>
        </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert("Hi");
            map = new GMaps({
              div: '#map',
              lat: -12.043333,
              lng: -77.028333
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I there is a way to do that without additional plugins that would be be perfect.
Thanks

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle that potential solvers can work with?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve by placing a transparent div above the map?

Comment: @Vidur, I tried to add a jsfiddle but i was not able to load gmaps there because it is on github (no cdn), and i did not find a way to upload it there. What I want is to be able to set text on top of the map like in this page: http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-google-map-plugins/

Comment: JSFiddle has an option to link to external dependencies too. Can you post what is in the gmaps.js file? Or link to it here?

Comment: @Vidur here is the url of tgmaps: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HPNeo/gmaps/master/gmaps.js and I am gonna copy the content in the original post

Comment: @Vidur I was not able to copy paste the content but I think with the URL that I provided is already good right?